# Sharing ownership of boost::shared_ptr after construction

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

Suppose I have two `boost::shared_ptr`'s pointing to two different objects of `class A`:

```
boost::shared_ptr<A> x = boost::make_shared<A>();
boost::shared_ptr<A> y = boost::make_shared<A>();
```

At some point, I need `x` to discard ownership of the object it's owning and share ownership of the `y`'s object with `y`. How can this be achieved (note that both shared_ptr's are constructed at that point, so no chance to use the copy constructor)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply assign it:

```
x = y;
```

See the [assignment operators for std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator%3D) and [boost::shared_ptr assignment](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#Members). You can verify this by checking the reference count before and after the assignment. This example uses C++11's `std::shared_ptr` but `boost::shared_ptr` would yield the same results:

```
#include <memory>
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> x(new int);
    std::cout << x.use_count() << "\n"; // 1
    std::shared_ptr<int> y(new int);
    std::cout << x.use_count() << "\n"; // still 1
    y = x;
    std::cout << x.use_count() << "\n"; // 2
}
```

Comment: According to the documentation, the assignment operator swaps (i.e. doesn't share) ownership, right?

Comment: @HaithamGad it shares the ownership of the RHS pointer, so `x` relinquishes ownership of the pointer it was constructed with, and shares ownership of the one managed by `y`.